# Flash Builder - Retain files in File.applicationStorageDirectory during multiple debug runs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I was just wondering if it was possible to retain files copied into the File.applicationStorageDirectory across multiple debugging sessions in Flash Builder?

I'm using it to store the application's database, after copying it over from the actual application directory (File.applicationDirectory) if it doesn't already exist in the user storage folder, and it'd be useful to not have to start with the base database every time.

I've had a look through the Debug configuration in Flash Builder, but couldn't find anything that seemed related. If anyone has any ideas, or workaround tips, it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the data is saved between instances. In the Debug Configuration, at the bottom of the window, there is an option labelled "Clear application data on each launch" that will automatically wipe that directory each time your launch a new debug instance.

Comment: How on EARTH did I not see that? Apologies world for wasting your time, and thanks Josh for putting me straight.